# AngularJS 1.2.21 forEach is not compatible with ng-grid?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, foreach, ng-grid, watch

Is there a **bug** related to forEach in AngularJS 1.2.21 that was not in AngularJS 1.2.20 ?

I tested the following code (when the ng-grid is loaded):

```
var contor = 0;
$scope.$watch('gridOptions.$gridScope.columns', functionForColumnsChange, true);
...
function functionForColumnsChange(newv, oldv) {
    if ( newv !== oldv ) {
        console.log(contor++);
    }
}
```

If I use:

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.20/angular.js

the output is

> 0

but if I use

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.js

the output is

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'sortPriority' of undefined
>       at http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/lib/ng-grid.js:1668:36
>       at Object.forEach (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.js:325:18)
>       at self.sortData (http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/lib/ng-grid.js:1667:25)
>       at self.sortColumnsInit (http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/lib/ng-grid.js:1701:18)
>       at Object.ngGridDirectives.directive.ngGridDirective.compile.pre.grid.init.then.dataWatcher
>   [as fn] (http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/lib/ng-grid.js:2943:42)
>       at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.js:12471:29)
>       at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.js:12736:24)
>       at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.js:1438:15
>       at Object.invoke (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.js:3940:17)
>       at doBootstrap (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.js:1436:14)
>
> 0
>
> 1

Why that error ?
And why 1 after 0 ?

If I change the ng-grid.js commenting 2 lines:

```
//c.sortPriority = i + 1;
//push(c);
```

the error message is not there anymore, but there is "1".

The ng-grid that is used is from this source: http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/lib/ng-grid.js (there is the same problem for the minified version).

---

**Later edit:**
The problem seems to be related to this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/36625de0d3ebc1fc091af474d942c6ce16b0a1c0

The difference is only in **Google Chrome** and **Mozilla Firefox**.

In **IE8** 0 and 1 are printed for both versions of AngularJS.
Output in IE8:

> TypeError: 'undefined' is null or not an object
>
> 0
>
> 1

Comment: What is the bug with `$watch`..? The `ng-grid` library youre using is causing an error on the different angular version, what do you expect `$watch` to behave like? Do you know what's going wrong within the library and what it does on errors?

Comment: Attach your code, make a JSFiddle, what you have now is not enough to reproduce the issue. The `ng-grid` is iterating over an array of columns and one of those is undefined. Try to make a JSFiddle that reproduces the issue on both versions.

Comment: What you could do is replace the forEach function on the global angular object, and fall back on the old functionality you linked on Github.

Comment: I found a workaround for this problem. I took the AngularJS code on my local machine and I added a condition before the line because the array seems to be sparse. So, I changed the forEach source code adding: if ( typeof obj[key] !== 'undefined' ) in the for loop.

Comment: A better solution was to modify just ng-grid to work with the new AngularJS:
            if (isArr) {
                angular.forEach(col, function (c, i) {
     if ( typeof c !== 'undefined' ) {
      c.sortPriority = i + 1;
      push(c);
     }
                });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I had a wrong `$scope.sortInfo` array:

```
$scope.sortInfo = {fields: ["N", "A", "B", "C"], directions: ['asc']};
```

even if "N" is not a column at this moment.

I found 3 possible solutions:

1)
**Change** the **array**:

```
$scope.sortInfo = {fields: ["A", "B", "C"], directions: ['asc']};
```

2) **Change** the **ng-grid** to be more permissive:

```
                if ( typeof c !== 'undefined' ) {
                    c.sortPriority = i + 1;
                    push(c);
                }
```

3) **Change** the **AngularJS** to be more permissive:

```
for (key = 0; key < obj.length; key++) {
    if ( typeof obj[key] !== 'undefined' ) {
        iterator.call(context, obj[key], key);
    }
}
```